# Autocorrect gives example comma insertion, but I think it's wrong?

Tags: punctuation

I encountered this correction in IntelliJ, a tool for editing computer programs:

[image]

Is this right? I feel like there is an implicit "that" in the sentence:

> I need to borrow some money so [that] I can buy some medicine for Tom.

And therefore the second clause is really a dependent clause in disguise. What do the experts say?

Comment: Compare with "I was tired after working all day, so I decided to go to bed early."https://www.pfw.edu/offices/learning-support/documents/combining-independent-and-dependent-clauses.pdf

Comment: @Phil Sweet No; that's a wrong comparison. You have the _so_ = _[and] therefore_ usage; OP has the _so [that] [I can]_ = _to enable me to_ usage, as they suggest. The comma is unneeded (and I'd not use it; to show an afterthought, I'd use brackets: _I need to borrow some money (so [that] I can buy some medicine for Tom)_).

Comment: There's a reason that "autocorrect" is widely referred to as "autocorrupt".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that was my point. The link gives further explanation.

Comment: I guess I should have said *contrast with*.